# How to check if the cookies with the name exist in the browser or not and allow the authority to the particuar page on the basis of it

Tags: javascript, express

I  am crating an authorisation system using express, node and MySQL so i used jwt token  to authorise user now i have stored the jwt to the cookies now, i want to check if the jwt exist in cookie or not if exist then allow the user to access the page or else should redirect to login page

Comment: Create some middleware that gets the desired cookie from [`req.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.cookies) and checks if it contains a valid jwt token.  If so, then call `next()` and allow the request routing to continue.  If not, don't call `next()` and call `res.redirect("/login")`.

Comment: @jfriend003 can you tel me some exaples how that can be acheived or some documentation link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some middleware that gets the desired cookie from `req.cookies` and checks if it contains a valid jwt token. If so, then call `next()` and allow the request routing to continue. If not, don't call next() and call `res.redirect("/login")`.

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(cookieParser(), function(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.cookies.myCookieName;
    if (token && verify(token)) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

You supply the `verify()` function that checks to see if the token we retrieved from the cookie is valid.  You supply the cookie name which is shown here as `myCookieName` (whatever cookie name you previously stored the jwt token on).

If the `verify()` function needs to be asynchronous (perhaps check a database), then this could be adapted to only call `next()` upon a successful asynchronous completion callback.

Comment: is there any way to check that cookie at the client side with just javascript

Comment: @Avinash - If the cookie is not set to `HttpOnly` (which blocks client-side Javascript access), then you can access a cookie for your own page from browser Javascript using the [document.cookie API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).  But, you can't "verify" anything there because client-side verification is untrusted and can easily be bypassed.  Authorization access must be enforced server-side.